# Is it possible to clear the java console?

Tags: java

I am writing a program which gets numbers from the user (using a `Scanner`) frequently. But before getting a new number, I want to clean the console from the previous result.

I tried `System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");` but it did not work.

Comment: you need to flush System.out.flush();

Answer (score 0):

**tldr;**

Linux Solution:

```
public static void clearScreen() {  
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
}
```

Windows Solution:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

**NOTE:** On Windows OS, you can have a problem with redirecting output to newly created process. To solve this, please use `ProcessBuilder` instead.

```
public class ClearScreen {
    public static void main(String... arg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a **new** command window and clearing it does nothing whatsoever to clear the **current** command window.